# Sametime Java Toolkit loginByPassword deprecated

Tags: java, deprecated, toolkit, sametime

First I would like to start off with the info that I have just started as an intern at a company that works with IBM software. So please forgive me if I am making rookie mistakes.

I was doing the Java Toolkit tutorial today from de Sametime 8.5.2 SDK. While following the tutorial I noticed that some of the methods used in the tutorial where marked by Eclipse as deprecated. I assume this is because the tutorial is not updated.

Unfortunately, they don't seem to have a Javadoc description and I can't find any info on what I should use instead of the deprecated methods. A concrete example is the "loginByPassword" method from the communityservice (com.lotus.sametime.community.CommunityService).

I tried to find info about this subject, however I can not find any. This makes me think I might be doing something wrong.

So I have three questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. If so, what am I doing wrong?
3. If I am not doing anything wrong, can someone please point me to a place where I can find the documentation I require?

Comment: I forgot about that fact that I could use the context menu to find methods. It seems like some constructors of loginByPassword are partially deprecated, so that sort of solves that. I say sort of, cause I still don't know why they are deprecated. I'd still appreciate it if someone has a better solution for this but I'll do with what I have in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. There is a seperate Javadoc folder that is included with the SDK. The Javadoc contains info about most of the classes.